# How we can add xpath information in schematron error message output

Tags: xquery, xslt-2.0, marklogic, schematron

I am using schematron API in MarkLogic to validate the XML document. Below is the snippet of code for reference.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace sch = "http://marklogic.com/validate" at 
"/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/validate.xqy";

import module namespace transform = "http://marklogic.com/transform" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/transform.xqy";

declare namespace xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/not-Transform";

declare namespace iso = "http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron";


let $document :=
      document{
        <book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
              <title>Some Title</title>
              <chapter>
              <para>...</para>
              </chapter>
        </book>
      }

let $schema := 
    <s:schema xmlns:s="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
              xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
       <s:ns prefix="db" uri="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"/>
       <s:pattern name="Glossary 'firstterm' type constraint">
          <s:rule context="db:chapter">
             <s:assert test="db:title">Chapter should contain title</s:assert>
          </s:rule>
       </s:pattern>
     </s:schema>
return
 sch:schematron($document, $schema)
```

Can anyone help me out to get the XPath information of the context node along with schematron error message output.

Comment: Instead of using ML schematron validation API, you can try XSLT based schematron validation by which you can easily get XPATH. Have a look on SVRL

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for what I think you are asking for.

If you want the xpath of an item you can use `xdmp:path`. in order to get the xpath of the whole document you'll just have to walk the tree, which is what the recursive function `local:getXpathDeep` is doing. You can change the formatting of the output from the `string-join` that I used, it just made it easier to read for me. I created an XML output to put both the schematron results and the XPath into but you can just return a sequence if you like or put it into a map.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace sch = "http://marklogic.com/validate" at 
"/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/validate.xqy";

import module namespace transform = "http://marklogic.com/transform" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/transform.xqy";

declare namespace xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/not-Transform";

declare namespace iso = "http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron";

declare function local:getXpathDeep($node){
  (
    xdmp:path($node), 
    if (fn:exists($node/*)) then (
      local:getXpathDeep($node/*)
    ) else ()
  )
};

let $document :=
      document{
        <book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
              <title>Some Title</title>
              <chapter>
              <para>...</para>
              </chapter>
        </book>
      }

let $schema := 
    <s:schema xmlns:s="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
              xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
       <s:ns prefix="db" uri="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"/>
       <s:pattern name="Glossary 'firstterm' type constraint">
          <s:rule context="db:chapter">
             <s:assert test="db:title">Chapter should contain title</s:assert>
          </s:rule>
       </s:pattern>
     </s:schema>
return
  <result>
    <contextNodeXpath>{fn:string-join(local:getXpathDeep($document), " 
    " )}</contextNodeXpath>
    <schematronOutPut>{sch:schematron($document, $schema)}</schematronOutPut>
  </result>
```

Answer (score 0):

That particular Schematron module is rather limited and does not provide a way to return the XPath for the context node from a report or failed assert.

The standard Schematron SVRL output does include the XPath for the items that fire failed asserts or reports.

Norm Walsh has published the [ML-Schematron module](https://github.com/ndw/ML-Schematron) that wraps the compilation of a Schematron schema into an XSLT using the Schematron stylesheets, and subsequent execution of the compiled XSLT to generate the SVRL report.

You could adjust your module to use it instead (after installing it and the [standard Schematron XSLT files](https://github.com/Schematron/schematron/tree/master/trunk/schematron/code) in your Modules database):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl";
import module namespace sch="http://marklogic.com/schematron" at "/schematron.xqy";

let $document :=
      document{
        <book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
              <title>Some Title</title>
              <chapter>
              <para>...</para>
              </chapter>
        </book>
      }

let $schema := 
    <s:schema xmlns:s="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
              xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
       <s:ns prefix="db" uri="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"/>
       <s:pattern name="Glossary 'firstterm' type constraint">
          <s:rule context="db:chapter">
             <s:assert test="db:title">Chapter should contain title</s:assert>
          </s:rule>
       </s:pattern>
     </s:schema>

return
  sch:validate-document($document, $schema)
```

It produces the following SVRL report, which includes the XPath in the location attribute `/*[local-name()='book']/*[local-name()='chapter']`:

```
<svrl:schematron-output title="" schemaVersion="" xmlns:schold="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" 
xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias" 
xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl">
  <!---->
  <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values uri="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" prefix="db"/>
  <svrl:active-pattern document=""/>
  <svrl:fired-rule context="db:chapter"/>
  <svrl:failed-assert test="db:title" location="/*[local-name()='book']/*[local-name()='chapter']">
    <svrl:text>Chapter should contain title</svrl:text>
  </svrl:failed-assert>
</svrl:schematron-output>
```